# Compare String with split in contains - LINQ

Tags: linq

My requirement is to compare the values in string with the list of string.

Code:

```
string Names = "Prabha,Karan";
        List<string> Presenter = new List<string> { "Prabha", "Joe", "Hukm" };

bool Presented = Presenter.Contains(Names.Split(','));
```

the above code throws an error and here i need to find the names are presented in the presenter(Presenter has the splited values of the Names).

Comment: Just so you know the reason this doesn't work is because you are passing a list into contains but contains only checks a single. ub1k's answer looks like a good solution though

Comment: Please precise: Do you want to receive `true` on every elements from Names being present in Presenter or Any.. ? so your code above.. should it (if it worked) return true or false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do it like below:

```
var splitNames = Names.Split(',');
bool Presented = Presenter.Any(p => splitNames.Contains(p));
```

EDIT:

If you're interested what are the matches just do:

```
var matches = Presenter.Where(p => splitNames.Contains(p))
```

Comment: returns Presented==true on any element from Names being any element from Presenter. Yes it works. I always build/test code that I post.

Comment: Just did unit test and it not works ( presented = Presenter.Any() )(I've not used code that you've posted later as EDIT because I asked before EDIT was added)

Answer (score 0):

```
string names = "Prabha,Karan"; 
List<string> presenter = new List<string> { "Prabha", "Joe", "Hukm" };
IEnumerable<string> namesList = names.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
var list = presenter.Intersect(namesList);
bool presented = namesList.Count() == list.Count());
```

The unit tests to cover your case:

```
[Test]
public void AllSourceEntriesAreFoundInTheTargetList()
{
    string names = "Prabha,Karan"; 
    List<string> presenter = new List<string> { "Prabha", "Joe", "Hukm" };
    IEnumerable<string> namesList = names.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());

    var list = presenter.Intersect(namesList);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(namesList.Count(), list.Count());

    presenter = new List<string> { "Prabha", "Karan", "SomeAnother" };
    var list1 = presenter.Intersect(namesList);
    Assert.AreEqual(namesList.Count(), list1.Count());
}
```